# Want to ping lambda responsiveness upto 4 or 5 seconds or less

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When a user activates the lambda, it takes 14-15 seconds to warm, I want responsiveness less with less than 5 seconds or even lesser than the same.

How would I achieve this logic, I have 3 lambda function where I have to use this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create another Lambda Function to ping all your microservices.
2. Create Cloud Rules that trigger the Lambda Function every few seconds/minutes.
3. Pass in the parameters which are your microservices health endpoint.

```
{
    "targets": [{
        "url": "https://lambda-url1",
        "name": "lambda-1"
    },{
        "url": "https://lambda-url2",
        "name": "lambda-2"
    },{
        "url": "https://lambda-url3",
        "name": "lambda-3"
    }],
    "timeout": 3000,
    "namespace": "bla"
}
```

Below is a ready-to-use lambda-warmer function, you could take it as reference:
[Lambda Warmer](https://github.com/jeremydaly/lambda-warmer)

[image]

Comment: Cloudwatch should be under free tier, unless there's too many calls. You could learn more here. [cloudwatch pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/)

Of course, Lambda is still charged as per call, but I suggest the price hike will be minimum